# How does XML document work with GTK to create user interface?

Tags: c, xml, gtk

I am working on a C/GTK+3 project right now. I have a little experience with front end but mostly only with Android. Even then that was VERY LITTLE experience.

I notice that in the C code I place objects and set properties (like if a textview is editable etc). I also have been able to connect a .ui XML file to my program with the builder functions.

I am wondering how the XML file gets linked to the C code defining the interface. Does it match by structure, by the name or ID properties? Why are properties like "visible" and "editable" present in both the C code and the XML? Do you need the XML file? Do you need to specify the properties in both the XML file and the C code or just one? Will I ever completely understand front end development?

Comment: It's a while ago when I switched from gtkmm 2.x to Qt (because gtkmm3 and Windows didn't work well together for us) but the [`GTKUIManager`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkUIManager.html) seems still to be there. It can be used to read UI files but you can also provide XML code in strings "inline".

Comment: Found something else: [Building applications - Populating the window](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html#id-1.2.3.12.6)

Comment: Btw. you don't need the UI files nor the `GTKUIManager` - it's actually for convenience. We usually created all widgets in pure C++ code, ehem, in C code in your case. Or, do you asking for [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/)? (Sorry, no experience - not at all.)

Comment: I'm so relieved to hear that I don't need the UI files/GTKUIManager! I am not using glade but I was just following the tutorials (the populating the window one you posted actually) and was wondering as a beginner to UI where all these XML files tied in and how.

Comment: See e.g. [GtkLabel](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html). The page provides samples with and without UI definition.

Comment: Thank you you've been super helpful!

Comment: Please don't use `GtkUIManager`, it has been deprecated since GTK+ 3.10. Use `GtkBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two ways of constructing a user interface:

1. You write the code for it.
2. You write a file that describes the user interface, and have the user interface built for you at runtime.

If you write the code yourself, everytime you want to move widgets around, you have to modify your code, that you'll need to compile. That is doable for a small UI, and is what is done in most tutorials.

If you use ui files, then you use the [Glade](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Glade) application to design your UI graphically, and it will write the UI files for you. This helps in splitting responsabilities too: you may have design people taking care of the UI, and let developpers focus on the behavior. Even without that, you'll be able to design a UI faster with an editor like Glade than by coding it by hand. Think you skip all the compile/debug cycles.

In your ui file, if you name a wigdet "bob", you'll be able to get it in your code by passing its name to [`gtk_builder_get_object`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-get-object). `GtkBuilder` takes care of the construction and the memory, so don't destroy the widgets it creates if you need to display them again, and hide them instead.

You have examples of use of UI files in the GTK documentation:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html#id-1.2.3.12.5

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me understand, I appreciate it!